# AJAX: Jumping to another section in page created dynamically by PHP using xmlhttp.open (does onClick() run before href?)

Tags: php, javascript, css, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'd like to click on an element in a list which will populate another list and take me to it; the second list needs to be loaded from a mySQL database using AJAX & PHP. I would like to know if the following approach is possible, or if a better one exists.

HTML:

```
<a onClick=loadContent(this.value) value=Section1 href="#!/Section1">Section 1</a>

<li id=output></li>
```

Javascript:

```
function loadContent(section)
{
      .
      .
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
       document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getContent.php?q="+section,true);
xmlhttp.send()
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
   $q=$_GET["q"];

   //connecting and creating query etc.

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
      print "\t" . '<li id=". $q ."><a href="#!/"'  . $row['subsection'] .'>' . $row['subsection'] . '</a></li>';
   }
   ?>
```

So will the PHP create the section before the href in HTML grabs it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that won't work because the Ajax is asynchronous. The Ajax call will be fired off, but then `loadContent()` will immediately complete before the result is returned, and so it will try to go to `#!/Section1` before the content has been inserted.

What can do is move to the anchor after the Ajax completes (in the readyState part), using:

```
window.location.hash = '#!/Section1';
```